# UIPopoverPresentationController object doesn't get de-allocated inside delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uipopovercontroller

I got a subclass of `text field(cInputField)`, and this subclass consist of one delegate that call back to open a popover in parent view.

- cInputField object in parent view

  ```
  self.agencyField.inputType = PopupPicker;
  self.agencyField.indicator = Filter;
  self.agencyField.cInputFieldDeleagate = self;
  self.agencyField.text = @"";
  self.agencyField.placeholder = RWLocalizedString(@"Select Agency", @"Select Agency");
  ```
- invoke delegate method

  ```
  [self.cInputFieldDeleagate performSelector:@selector(popupPickerTouchUpEvent:) withObject:self];
  ```
- CInputField delegate method

  ```
  - (void)popupPickerTouchUpEvent:(CInputField *)cInputField {
      [self openAgencyPicker:cInputField];
  }
  ```
- open popup function

  ```
  - (void)openAgencyPicker:(id)sender{

      if (!agencyPicker) {
      agencyPicker = [[CPickerController alloc]
                      initWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500)];

      agencyPicker.displayTitle = RWLocalizedString(@"SFA.Product.Agency", @"Agency");
      agencyPicker.items = [SalesDataManager getRclAgencyListByShipTo:[[OrderState sharedInstance] orderHeader].storeCd];
      agencyPicker.valueMember = @"value";
      agencyPicker.displayMember = @"text";
      agencyPicker.delegate = self;
      agencyPicker.selectedIndex = -1;

      agencyContentNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:agencyPicker];
      agencyContentNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
     }

      [[AppD menuViewController] presentViewController:agencyContentNav animated:YES completion:nil];

      popOverPresentController = agencyContentNav.popoverPresentationController;
      popOverPresentController.sourceView = [sender superview];
      popOverPresentController.sourceRect = popOverRect;
      popOverPresentController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
  }
  ```

**Problem**

after adding the code in below, my form didn't get de-allocated in the Xcode instrument (allocation mode)

```
[[AppD menuViewController] presentViewController:agencyContentNav animated:YES completion:nil];

popOverPresentController = agencyContentNav.popoverPresentationController;
popOverPresentController.sourceView = [sender superview];
popOverPresentController.sourceRect = popOverRect;
popOverPresentController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
```

Any idea what's wrong here? much appreciate if anyone could help.